Unresolved reference after upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 8.3
I have an Android build.gradle file that uses an alternate sourceSets declared as stated by the AGP documentation :
android {
    sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs = [main.res.srcDirs, "build/generated/res/main"]
    }
}

The build works fine until AGP 8.2.2 but after upgrading to AGP 8.3 (tested 8.3, 8.3.2, 8.5.0) I got

Unresolved reference for all resources both in src/main/res and build/generated/res/main (every single R.*.* are not resolved across all .java / .kt files)

If I remove the custom sourceSets declaration then I got :

Unresolved reference only for the custom resources generates under build/generated/res/main

Does anyone knows about a change that happen in AGP 8.3 for declaring/referencing custom resource directories that have not been reflected in the doc ?

Looks like it's related to the "build/generated" directory only that may be modified after referencing sourceSets...
